# How to find forward reference in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

Is there any way by which I can find out all classes which implement a particular interface?
For example, if I have a interface as follows:

```
public interface myIntFac{}
```

I want to find all classes inside current project that implement this interface. How can I find it out in Eclipse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the interface level, you can use (assuming the cursor in on the interface)

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to show the **Quick Type Hierarchy**
- <kbd>F4</kbd> to **Open Type  Hierarchy**

At the method level, if you hover a method while holding down the control key, a pop-up box gives you the following choices:

- Open Declaration
- Open Implementation

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/images/open-implementation.png))</sub>

And from anywhere, you can use:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Open Type  Hierarchy** pop-up and search for any type/interface.

Answer (score 2):

Place your cursor on the interface, and try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Put your cursor in `myIntFac` and press F4 to show the type hierarchy as a separate window, or Ctrl-T to show it as a pop-up. Personally I like the "separate window" approach as it makes it easier to browse, refocus on a different type etc - but if you only want to show the hierarchy very briefly, the pop-up is good too.